# How do I have conda list command print just the name column?

Tags: python, conda

I'm aware that `conda list` command prints all the packages in the current conda environment, e.g.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.2.0               eigen.conda
absl-py                   0.11.0          pyhd3eb1b0_1.conda
```

How do I have it print just the name column, like

```
# Name       
_tflow_select
absl-py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) with the `|` operator to print it out as follows:

```sh
conda list | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed you can use the `--json` argument with `conda list` to export the output as json and then filter with `jq` the `name` fields:

```sh
conda list --json | jq '.[] | .name'
```

You will obtain the following output:

```sh
"_tflow_select"
"absl-py"
```

To remove the double quotes, use `sed`:

```sh
conda list --json | jq '.[] | .name' | sed 's/"//g'
```

You will obtain the desired output:

```sh
_tflow_select
absl-py
```